# Get selected index/indices in a bootstrap multiselect control element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a Bootstrap multiselect element which looks something like this:

[image]

I know how I can retrieve the value of the selected item, i.e.   `$('#multiselectElement').val();`

This code could return e.g.  `['Cheese', 'Mozzarella,', 'Onions']`

The things is, I need not the item values, but their INDICES. My intention is to return `[0, 2, 5]` instead of `['Cheese', 'Mozzarella,', 'Onions']`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your values the indexes...

```
<select id="example-single">
    <option value="0">Cheese</option>
    <option value="1">Tomato</option>
    <option value="2">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="3">Onions</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Select the option elements...

```
$('#multiselectElement option:selected').map(function(a, item){return item.value;});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of clicked item:

```
$('#multiselectElement *').click(function(){
$(this).index()
});
```